# React Navigation, launch screen outside drawer navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a nested `Stacks` in my `Drawer`:

```
const routes = {
    Home: {
        screen: withHeader(HomeScreen, "Home", BasicHeader)
    },
    ...
    VideoPlayer: {
        screen: VideoPlayerScreen
    },
    TestYourself: {
        screen: withHeader(TestYourselfScreen, "Test Yourself", DrawerHeader)
    },
    MyResults: {
        screen: withHeader(MyResultsScreen, "My Results", DrawerHeader)
    },
    ...
};

const AppNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(routes, config);
```

How can I open a screen outside of my drawer navigator?

I would like to open my `VideoPlayer` screen in a `Stack` rather than a `Drawer`, as the Drawer stops my `React-native-youtube` component from playing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you nest your DrawerNavigator in your StackNavigator, you can open your VideoPlayerScreen outside of your DrawerNavigator.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [drawerlockmode](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/drawerlayoutandroid.html#drawerlockmode), in constructor of `VideoPlayer` you can set it to `locked-closed` and in `componentWillUnmount()` set it back to `unlocked`